# Newbie Problems with Visual Studio Community 2019: Error Codes LNK2019 & LNK1120 in a Simple C Project

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2019, build-error

I started learning the Windows API in C today, and also started using Visual Studio Community 2019. I created a file called `main.c` with the following code, and put it in a project called `Test Program`.

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    return 0;
}
```

That was the only file in the project, and when I build the project I get the following errors:

[image]

Can I please get some help with this?

**EDIT: PLEASE READ**

I figured out the answer to this. All you need to do is simply re-create the project in Visual Studio, and follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=vs-2019).

Comment: [theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html)

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't I be using wWinMain()? That's what Microsoft recommends. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point)

Comment: You can, I've use `_cdecl _tmain()` and a host of others. What compiler are you using? See [Walkthrough: Compile a C program on the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019. I found a tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=vs-2019), and I'm going to try the method for creating that project, but using my own code. Hopefully that will solve my problem, I'm thinking that it'll tell the compiler that I'm building a desktop program and not a console program.

Comment: Okay, that works. I'm assuming it was just a change of compiler flags that happened when I created the new project as a desktop application instead of an empty project. I'm thinking that the empty project was targeting a console application.

Comment: Good luck. Just my .02 -- I often found configuring a project in VS more work than actually learning how to build and compile the program. VS comes with the *VS Developer's Command Prompt* which gives you a full build environment (all library paths set, etc..) and you can simply build using the actual compiler `cl.exe` on the command line without a project. `cl /?` for options. Use `/Tc` for a single source compile as C or `/TC` for compile all sources as C. (theForgers's tutorial is really good for this)

Comment: For example, take the `bmp_two` tutorial from theForger's source files (it displays copies of a bitmap ball in a window). Open the Developer's Command Prompt, switch to the directory containing the sources, compile the resource file to a `.res` file with `rc /Fobmp_two.res bmp_two.rc` (the `/Fo` option specifies the object file output name. Then compile the program, `cl /nologo /Febmp_two /Tc bmp_two.c user32.lib bmp_two.res gdi32.lib`  Then just run it `bmp_two.exe`. The `/Fe` option is executable output name (`.exe` automatically added) That's it!

Answer (score 0):

The C program requires a void main() function. It is where your program starts. You must add a void main function to your code.

Comment: Yes, but when I add that to my code, it starts at main(), shouldn't it start at wWinMain() with windows.h?

Comment: There is no requirement that the main function be called `void main()`